# Getting the E-mail id of user in Bigquery

Tags: google-oauth, google-bigquery

I am using Bigquery Java API. For authorization with Bigquery service,I am using Google OAuth 2.0.My question is :- How to get an E-mail ID of user who has granted the access on consent screen?

I am not able to find anything related to it. Is it possible to get an E-mail ID of the User. 
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The only way I know of is to go though the google+ api https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get  (yes I know its nasty but like I said its the only way I have found)

Comment: is there any another example that you have found ?

Comment: The only other way I have found to get the email is by hacking Id_token that is returned from the Oauth.   I don't know if its part of the java client library or not https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/aaa_idtoken  but if memory serves the authenticated users email is in there.    I don't have any expense with the java client library but I know its not part of the .net client library.  Sorry I cant be of more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run

`SELECT CURRENT_USER()`

and this returns the current user's email

You can find this, and more functions in the manual: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Pentium10's suggestion, you can also get the user e-mail of the user who ran a particular job / query; it is in the user_email property of the job. You can see this by using bq by doing:

```
$ bq show --format=prettyjson -j project_id:job_id | grep user_email
```

Where project_id:job_id are the project and job id for the job you're looking for.

This only works to get the user e-mail if either you are a project administrator or you were the one who ran the job in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the user's email address as part of the OAuth flow. It looks like it's part of the JWT that you receive during this process:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

If you're using a language-specific client library, there may be support in that client library for decoding the JWT.